# Does gnome-software hide applications?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-software

I am using a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.10 with the default gnome desktop. I tried installing the qtcreator IDE, and wasn't able to find it with the gnome software center (`gnome-software`), so I installed it with `apt`.

I tried qt (which does not find anything, probably it expects three letters at minimum or so), qtcreator (which is the package name), qt creator and variations with qt5 as search strings. It sometimes found things, but nothing that has to do with the framework. `qtcreator` is in the universe/devel section, and universe section is enabled.

I wonder why and where these rules are defined or is this even a bug?

NOTE: This is about `gnome-software` as in the default installation of Ubuntu 17.10, not the Ubuntu Software Center from previous Ubuntu Unity versions.

Comment: Known bug: LP#1724489 Searching ignores less than 3 chars words

Comment: Known bug: LP#1721647 qtCreator does not appear to have correct appstream data  (*This is the important one that prevents qtCreator from showing in Gnome-Software*)

Comment: If anybody wants to volunteer a bit of time to work with the Gnome project, upstream these bugs,  and create patches to fix these bugs, your effort will be welcome. Bugs don't fix themselves.

Comment: @user535733 Your second comment ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator/+bug/1721647 ) is definitely an answer, why don't you create this as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Ubuntu Software has been GNOME Software for a few releases now (since 16.04, IIRC).